# list of style properties that is specific to each components in React-native ( CSS )

Tags: css, react-native, styles, components

I would like to have the list of style properties that is specific to each components.
And the list of style properties that is compatible with all components.
CSS React-native

```
StyleSheet.create({
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***We have six categories :***
[image]

For more information:

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.25/docs/style.html